# jquery qTip: making callout stay there

Tags: jquery, qtip

How do I make a qTip callout show when the page is loaded, and ALSO stay there even if I hover over the field.  In essence I just want a fixed callout, and am using qTip for its ease of positioning and styling.

Note: I tried the "show: {ready: true}" setting, but this simply initially renders the call-out.  If one hovers over the associated target field, the call-out disappears.  I need it to show displayed, period.

Thanks

P.S.  I'm using the latest 1.* (stable version).

Adding the

```
  hide: { when: 'mouseout', fixed: true },
```

didn't seem to help either for some reason, nor did

```
  hide: {fixed: true }
```

Maybe I'm using these options wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
$("#tip").qtip({
    hide: false, // Don't specify a hide event
    show: { ready: true } // Show the qtip when ready.
});
```