# jquery library for callout

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

Can you recommend a jquery library that I can use for to make a callout that stays on the page ... not a tooltip that pops up and goes away.  Application is to mark a form field with an error, that is shown in a callout next to the field.  An example of a callout is shown in the [qtip library, see orange callout](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/features/#styles).

Qtip would be great if I could get the callout (tooltip) to be permanently fixed on the page, but I can't it to stay there, hence I want to use another library, that can provide me ease of positioning the callout just like qtip, with some style selection.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery qTip: making callout stay there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7394788/jquery-qtip-making-callout-stay-there)

Comment: David - am looking for a library that can do what I need, e.g. a simple callout.