# Programmable Callout JQuery Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I noticed on Facebook recently, that to introduce its new features, a callout appeared for the various new features (6 of them).  The callout appeared on the left to identify the first feature.  As you "X"ed it out, the next callout appeared to highlight the next feature, and so on.  This was awesome, so I wanted to add this feature to my site.  Is there a plugin available just for the callout part, which I can show, hide, and reposition?

Thanks.

Comment: I am not facebook user, os perhaps you want to include a screenshot of what you mean? How about qTip http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/

Comment: @d_inevitable Yes, that's a good one, will look into, thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery library for callout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7395136/jquery-library-for-callout)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up going for QTip 2: http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2, as @d_inevitable mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

There are several jQuery plugins that do that effectively. Here are some that come to mind:

- [Meow](http://zacstewart.com/projects/meow.html)

Google for growl-like notifications for more, there's plenty around.

Comment: Those are really good, I'm going to have to consider those too... but I'm looking along the lings of qtip2 as mentioned the comment...

Answer (score 1):

I have created a plugin that will allow you to do just this. You can find it there: https://github.com/devmnrj/myAlert

**Here is a little JS code demo:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myAlert = new MyAlert();
    window.onload = function(){
        $("#anchor").on("click", function(e){
            myAlert.show({'x':e.pageX, 'y':e.pageY}, {
                'header': "<em>Hello!</em><br/><small>I am a header</small>",
                'body': "I am the body of the dialog, so i should be bigger. Yeah, more text here. I can also update me <a>here</a>.",
                'footer': "footer: goodbye!"
            });
        });
    };
</script>
```